# Connection from .net to Progress.OpenClient throws Object is no longer available for use. (7260)

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus, openedge, progress-4gl

**Background**

My C# code hasn't been touched in a long time (1 year+), suddenly I get the following error when connecting to our `Progress` server:

```
Progress.Open4GL.Exceptions.Open4GLException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Object is no longer available for use. (7260) 
  Source=Progress.o4glrt
  StackTrace:
   at Progress.Open4GL.Proxy.OpenAppObject.RunProc(String procName, ParamArray paramArray)
   at My.Service.Progress.LoadStuff.<Handle>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\MyRepo\My.Service.Progress\LoadStuff.cs:line 34
```

This is called via a Progress client dll reference:

```
<package id="Progress.OpenClient" version="11.7.1" targetFramework="net471" />
```

Like so:

```
public async Task Handle(GetStuffToLoad message, IMessageHandlerContext context)
{
    var parameters = new ParamArray(4);

    parameters.AddCharacter(0, message.param1, ParamArrayMode.INPUT);
    parameters.AddCharacter(1, message.param2, ParamArrayMode.INPUT);
    parameters.AddDecimal(2, decimal.Parse(message.param3), ParamArrayMode.INPUT);
    parameters.AddLongChar(3, null, ParamArrayMode.OUTPUT);

    _trisClient.RunProc("loadStuff", parameters);

    var stuffContent = (string)parameters.GetOutputParameter(3);
}
```

**Symptoms**

- On the very first try, everything's okay. No errors.
- Doing a second call soon after the first gives the above error.
- I'm calling our TEST environment locally.
- As far as we know, TEST does not have the same symptoms.

I logged an earlier bugfix request to the Progress team, I got that when calling the progress TEST environment from multiple threads:

```
Progress.Open4GL.Exceptions.BusySessionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Session is busy. Another request is executing or there is an open result set(s). (7226) 
  Source=Progress.o4glrt
  StackTrace:
   at Progress.Open4GL.DynamicAPI.Session.runProcedure(String requestID, String procedureName, ParameterSet parms, Boolean persistent, Boolean internal_Renamed, Int64 procId, MetaSchema localSchema, Int32 stateModel)
```

At the time it was decided to refactor my side to not run in parallel, so that the underlying connections are flooded.

But, with what I found out now, I'm inclined to believe the two issues are related.

Both share that `HResult=0x80131500` report.

**What I think is going on**

As the first try works and the second doesn't, I think that either the progress TEST server, or the Progress OpenClient, does not correctly close a connection and/or transaction.

> What needs to happen to fix the issue? 
>   Is it something on my side or something with the Progress server (dll or actual server)?

Comment: Why do you have an NServiceBus tag on this?

Comment: That 'Handle' is an NSB method. It's async nature 'could' have an effect (although since it's been running fine for a long time, I more suspect the Progress side).

Comment: "As the first try works and the second doesn't, I think that either the progress TEST server, or the Progress OpenClient, does not correctly close a 
 connection and/or transaction."


IMHO That sounds like a reasonable assumption...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing async call use RunTimeProperties.WaitIfBusy = true; before Appserver connection is made.

Fyi RunTimeProperties is a class residing in Progress.Open4GL namespace in Progress.o4glrt.dll.